# Hiding markers using LeafletSlider?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am showing a temporal range of refugee camps on my map by using the [LeafletSlider plugin](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider). The camps appear on the map based on an attribute in my GEOJSON object called `DATE_START`. As you can see in my **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/doss1/sn02sna3/)**, the slider works good.

As I am scrubbing the timeline , I want to remove the markers that have a `DATE_CLOSED` property depending on the date of the current timeline scrub and the date of the `DATE_CLOSED` property.

**It looks like this timeslider plugin only shows markers. Does anyone know how to hide the markers after it date has closed?**

> Sample data:

```
var camps = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"STATUS":"UNOCCUPIED","DATE_START":"2015-06-23","DATE_CLOSED":"2016-01-23"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[64.6875,34.97600151317591]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"STATUS":"OCCUPIED","DATE_START":"2014-01-21","DATE_CLOSED":"2015-05-25"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[65.335693359375,36.26199220445664]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"STATUS":"UNOCCUPIED","DATE_START":"2015-09-13","DATE_CLOSED":""},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[67.587890625,35.969115075774845]}}]};
```

> Code:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
center: [33.67406853374198, 66.9287109375],
zoom: 7
}).addLayer(new L.TileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"));


//Create a marker layer (in the example done via a GeoJSON FeatureCollection)
var testlayer = L.geoJson(camps, {
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.DATE_START);
    }
});

var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
position: "topright",
layer: testlayer,
timeAttribute: 'DATE_START'
});

//Make sure to add the slider to the map ;-)
map.addControl(sliderControl);

sliderControl.options.markers.sort(function(a, b) {
return (a.feature.properties.DATE_START > b.feature.properties.DATE_START);
});

//And initialize the slider
sliderControl.startSlider();

$('#slider-timestamp').html(options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties.DATE_START.substr(0, 10));
```

Comment: LeafletSlider applies to only one property (the one set in the `timeAttribute` option), so you can't filter by both `DATE_START` and `DATE_CLOSED`. You may need to create your own control with a slider that filters your GeoJSON data using a [filter function](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-filter) that returns `true` for points whose `DATE_START` and `DATE_CLOSED` contain the slider date.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan. I don't think my skills are up to that level yet to create a custom slider, but thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this counts as an answer, but I discovered there was an alternative timeline plugin that does just what I needed: https://github.com/skeate/Leaflet.timeline